# Official test vectors for 3DES

Tags: .net, cryptography

https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-20.pdf Appendix A is not suitable for 3DES, since it uses simple 8-bytes DES keys which, when used, throw an error when tested on .NET Cryptography (known weak key exception).

Thus, is there anything for 3DES that uses at least 16 bytes keys? I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there aren't any official test vectors from NIST. [A set of test vectors](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/testvectors/bc/des/Triple-Des-2-Key-128-64.unverified.test-vectors) was created for the EU NESSIE project however.

With participants such as the COSIC faculty of the University of Leuven (home of many known cryptographers such as the authors of Rijndael / AES and Bart Preneel) you can take this project *very* seriously.

---

There also seems to be a set available within [ISO/IEC 18033](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:18033:-3:ed-2:v1:en) in case you want to shelf over CHF 178,00. I found those by searching for the official name of triple-DES: TDEA.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using this set. :)

Comment: Nice. Feel free to answer your own question if you find an answer, by the way. Note that there is also the [crypto sister site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) for questions that are not specific to development.